# Why is my application trying to read objects in the wrong folder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, directory-structure

I'm using visual studio to do my first full release of an application, which is a simple WPF GUI to configure a locally saved JSON object, and a console application to run in the background, using data from that object to monitor a website. I published each project to a test folder (we'll say Publish/), where each application manifest now resides, along with an 'Application Files' folder containing another sub-folder for each project.

I got the applications to run just fine - the problem is the configuration file saves to one folder a few more levels into C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\ and the console application is attempting to read from a completely separate folder. Both projects write and read using GetCurrentDirectory() for the file path. Is there a way I'm missing to remedy this?

Code for retrieving JSON object

```
try
        {
            //Confirms file exists
            if (File.Exists(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString() + filePath))
            {
                //Initialize json variable to a string, then deserialize it into an instance of RCDetails
                var json = File.ReadAllText(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString() + filePath);
                RCDetails parsedDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RCDetails>(json);

                //Return deserialized JSON
                return parsedDetails;
            }
            else return null;
```

And code for writing json object

```
public void WriteToFile(RCDetails rcd)
    {
        //Serialize input instance of RCDetails class
        string JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rcd, Formatting.Indented);

        //Remove old JSON object
        if (File.Exists(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString() + jsonFilePath))
            File.Delete(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString() + jsonFilePath);

        //Create new JSON object with updated details
        File.WriteAllText(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString() + jsonFilePath, JSONresult);
    }
```

Exact steps for publishing project:

- With console app selected, click Build > Publish (console app name)
- Browse to C:\Users\username\Downloads\Publish\
- For installation, choose "From a CD-ROM or DVD-ROM"
- Select "the application will not check for updates
- Select finish, and repeat all steps with same file path for config WPF

Solution I wound up finding (feel free to let me know if this is a bad plan). I just plopped this into both apps.

```
string s = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\IntendedFolder";
        if (!Directory.Exists(s))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(s);
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(s);
```

Comment: Please show relevant code.

Comment: It already describes what's relevant; adding the code won't provide any information that helps answer. But okay, editing now.

Comment: Are you making sure to start those applications from the correct folders?

Comment: @MichaelAlanNollette When your code isn't working as expected, you should not assume that your code is correct. So that's why it's helpful to provide code to potential answerers ;)

Comment: There's only one folder they successfully start from - the 'Publish/' folder that I published them to in the first place. The configuration WPF project successfully writes and reads the JSON - problem is each of them is directed to a different folder when using the GetCurrentDirectory() method. That said, this IS the first application I've ever actually published, so it's entirely possible I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Understood Stijn :-) The code's working correct - it just looks like the GetCurrentDirectory method for the config and main applications are each pointing in a different direction. The main app can still read the JSON if I manually copy and paste it in the folder it is looking at, but obviously that's not ideal when everyone who uses the app would have to do it to get it to work

Comment: If they are started from the same directory (i.e. the current directory is the same from whatever launches them), then `GetCurrentDirectory` would return the same value (barring a call to manually change the current directory).

Comment: Are these routines run from shortcuts? You can set the working folder there. Or, store a path in the registry and read from there. Maybe.

Comment: They are not run from shortcuts. And crashmstr, that's what I thought - maybe it's a quirk of visual studio's build process. I detailed the *exact* steps I took to publish the project in the post now.

Comment: No, I install and then run it both from the Publish folder that I published it to.

Comment: Answered my own question and added it - feel free to tag me if it's a stupid/bad practice solution, as it seems pretty...off

Comment: Small thing but please always use [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8) instead of just adding two strings together :)

Comment: Good to know @Joelius, thank you! That kind of stuff is what I'm trying to get the hang of before I get into the industry